# All pairs of letters (de Bruijn sequence with $n=2,k=52$)

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I’m designing a font and want to verify its kerning.

Ignoring punctuation, I want to generate a string made of $52$ symbols (uppercase `A` to `Z` and lowercase `a` to `z`), so that all possible letter pairs occur at least once.

I looked up similar problems, and it seems that what I want is a de Bruijn sequence. However, I couldn’t find anything online relating to an alphabet size $k>9$.

How long would my de Bruijn sequence be, and how would I go about generating said sequence?

Comment: http://debruijnsequence.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n=2$, such sequences are trivial to create. Begin with 'zA' and continually append the lowest value that completes a previously unseen pair:

zAABACAD...AxAyAzBBCBDBE...BxByBzCCDCECF....wwxwywzxxyxzyyzzA